# Fragment no longer attached to Activity

Tags: android, kotlin

It seems to be that after adding some code my fragment is not attached to the Activity anymore, but I can not figure out why. It was working fine before I changed the code to get editable Textboxes.
Once i start my Application i get the following Error out of the Logcat and the App closes instantly:

```
021-06-01 12:00:39.313 15077-15077/com.example.nlp_expense_tracker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.nlp_expense_tracker, PID: 15077
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nlp_expense_tracker/com.example.nlp_expense_tracker.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment Scanner{962f12d (5a3d4c39-2879-4913-a7bf-cab634718d36)} not attached to an activity.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment Scanner{962f12d (5a3d4c39-2879-4913-a7bf-cab634718d36)} not attached to an activity.
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireActivity(Fragment.java:802)
    at com.example.nlp_expense_tracker.fragments.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.kt:59)
    at com.example.nlp_expense_tracker.MainActivity.setUpTabs(MainActivity.kt:32)
    at com.example.nlp_expense_tracker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:25)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Here is my Fragments code:

```
   class Scanner : Fragment() {
private lateinit var imageView: ImageView
private lateinit var photoImage: Bitmap
private lateinit var mlkitImage: InputImage
private lateinit var editLocation: EditText
private lateinit var editVAT: EditText
private lateinit var editTotal: EditText


private val aldi = R.drawable.aldi

private val FILE_NAME= "photo.jpg"
private val REQUEST_CODE_KAMERA = 42
private val REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY = 69
private val CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE = 100
private var choosenImage: Bitmap? = null
@Inject
lateinit var receiptsViewModel: ReceiptsViewModel
private var resolver = requireActivity().contentResolver


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?):
        View? {val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scan, container, false)
    val btnTakePicture: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.btnTakePicture)
    imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView)
    editLocation = view.findViewById(R.id.editLocation)
    editTotal =view.findViewById(R.id.editTotal)
    editVAT = view.findViewById(R.id.editVAT)

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.aldi)
    choosenImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, aldi)
    
    //Button Picture
    btnTakePicture.setOnClickListener {
        checkPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE)
        val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity())
        builder.setTitle("Choose a Receipt")
        builder.setMessage("Either upload a Receipt or take a picture of one")
        // add the buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton("Use camera", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->

            startActivityForResult(receiptsViewModel.uploadIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_KAMERA)
        })

        builder.setNegativeButton("Upload from gallery", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
            startActivityForResult(receiptsViewModel.cameraIntent(activity!!), REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY)
        })
        val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()

    }
    return view
}
private fun uploadAction(data: Intent) {
    try {
        val stream = resolver!!.openInputStream(data.getData()!!)
        if (::photoImage.isInitialized) photoImage.recycle()
        photoImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream)
        mlkitImage = InputImage.fromBitmap(photoImage,0)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photoImage)
    } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
private fun cameraAction() {
    try {
        Picasso.get().load(receiptsViewModel.imageURI).into(imageView)
        mlkitImage = InputImage.fromFilePath(activity!!, receiptsViewModel.imageURI)
    } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

private fun textRecognitionAction() {

    var text = ""
    receiptsViewModel.textDetector.process(mlkitImage)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            for (block in it.textBlocks) text += block.text + "\n"
            val receipts = receiptsViewModel.getReceipts(text)
            editTotal.setText(receipts.total, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
            editLocation.setText(receipts.type, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
            editVAT.setText(receipts.vat, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
        }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        when (requestCode) {
            REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY -> uploadAction(data!!)
            REQUEST_CODE_KAMERA -> cameraAction()
        }
        textRecognitionAction()
    }
}

private fun checkPermission(permission: String, requestCode: Int) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity!!, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

        // Requesting the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity!!, arrayOf(permission), requestCode)
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(activity!!, "Permission already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

}

And my MainAcitiviy code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager
private lateinit var tabs: TabLayout

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager)
    tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs)
    setUpTabs()
}

private fun setUpTabs(){
    val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
    adapter.addFragment(HomeFragment(),"")
    adapter.addFragment(HistoryFragment(),"")
    adapter.addFragment(Scanner(),"")
    viewPager.adapter = adapter
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
    tabs.getTabAt(0)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_home_24)
    tabs.getTabAt(1)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_show_chart_24)
    tabs.getTabAt(2)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_receipt_24)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I just put the private var resolver = requireActivity().contentResolver int the uploadAction function and it works now :^)

Comment: Do you know the reason you had to do this? If not, I can write an explanation.